# Apple App store and free apps with paid activation key

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to know that if I have uploaded a free app on apple store, where any one can download it for free but after download user has to get a paid pin to activate the app form my site.

Will my app get rejected for this reason?

Comment: Like the local mob, Apple isn't ever going to let you make a profit without getting a cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is not allowed by apple and will most certainly get you app rejected.

From the app store approval [guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

> 11.1 - Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

You could use in-app purchases to unlock content.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you cannot make any purchases outside of App Store. Use In-App purchases instead.